# Query need optimizing or do I just need higher max connections?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, performance

I have a mysql database. My site has been getting a lot of max_user_connections errors, and since I can't increase the limit for a few more days, I was wondering if you guys could help me optimize this query that's taking between 1 and 4 seconds to complete. The 'status' table is InnoDB with 230,221 rows, and there are indexes already on it, but is it just a poorly written query?

```
SELECT status.id,users.id 
  FROM users, status 
 WHERE clan='someClan' 
   AND status.author!='loggedInUser' 
   AND status.anonymous!='someUser' 
   AND users.username='someUser' 
   AND status.data!='' 
   AND status.postdate > users.news_read 
GROUP BY postdate LIMIT 2
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN Your query` says ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid not quite sure how to use that.

Comment: Post output of [`Explain Query`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) hope this link will give idea how to use it

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I'm seeing the syntax, but I'm not seeing what to echo out to view the results.. am I missing something?

Comment: [*`See Sample explain demo`*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2392f/7) just put your real query with explain kewory and run on your machine and post the result of this statement here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the proper connection between the `users` and the `status` table. Right now you are returning size(users table) * size(status table) number of rows.

From your comments, let me assume that you know the current user's users.id.

```
SELECT status.id
  FROM status
 WHERE status.clan='someClan'     \\ assuming clan is in status table
   AND status.author!='someUser' 
   AND status.anonymous!='someUser'  
   AND status.data!='' 
   AND status.postdate > (Select users.news_read 
                            from users
                           where users.username='someUser' 
                         )
GROUP BY postdate LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Unfortunately the author and the username are not the same person. In fact it checks specifically for statuses written by someone who is not the logged in user. I've updated the question to represent this.

Comment: Well.. how ARE the two tables connected?

Comment: @Erstwhilelll the logged in users has a column dedicated to the last time they checked their feed. That's users.news_read. This is checked against the status table to see if any status.postdate values are later than the last time the user checked their feed.

Comment: So you KNOW the current user's users.id value then?

Comment: Correct. I actually don't even need that so I'm glad you mentioned that. All I need is a count of how many statuses match the query.

Comment: This worked VERY well! Looking at the process list, I haven't seen the query go over 350ms. Thank you!!!

Comment: Glad to have helped! Heck you could even vote my answer up (smile)

Comment: Haha. I tried. I don't have enough reputation sorry. :(